# Is there a way to break into a PostgreSQL database if you forgot the password?

Tags: database, postgresql, password-recovery

I have a client that has a PostgreSQL database and he cannot remember the password that we used when the database was setup. Is there a way to recover that information so I do not have to blow away his database and start from scratch?

The database is running on a PC.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on serverfault.com?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Step 1:** Edit PostgreSQL config file to establish trust relationship to login without password:

> vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

Old Line:

> local all postgres password

Change it to:

> local all postgres trust

**Step 2:** Restart PostgreSQL Server:

> service postgresql restart

**Step 3:** Change password:

> psql -U postgres template1 -c alter user postgres with password ‘newpassword’;

**Step 4:** Password has been updated. Revert back the original settings of config file:

> vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

Old Line:

> local all postgres trust

Change it to:

> local all postgres password

**Step 5:** Restart server and use your new password to access PostgreSQL Server.

> service postgresql restart

[Source](http://linuxadminzone.com/recover-or-reset-root-password-of-mysql-and-postgresql-servers/)

Comment: Does this still work? the directory  /var/lib/pgsql/data/ does not exist on my Ubuntu.

Comment: @why-el: On Ubuntu 12.04 the file is located under `/etc/postgresql/<version>/main/pg_hba.conf`. I verified that the instructions listed here still work.

Answer (score 2):

For 9.2, in windows:

Stop the service:

> Net stop postgresql-x64-9

Modify the config file,
change data/pg_hba.conf, basically md5 to trust:

> host   all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
>
> host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Start the service:

> Net start postgresql-x64-9

Execute the sql statement to set your desired password, on a sql console or using psql:

> alter user postgres with password ‘newpassword’;

Put back the original config file.