# Is there any way to protect PostgreSQL access via pgAdmin when an intruder changes pg_hba.conf file?

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, password-protection

I have a password protected PostgreSQL database (running on windows) which has been accessed by an unauthorized person several times using this simple trick [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922804/is-there-a-way-to-break-into-a-postgresql-database-if-you-forgot-the-password?):

1. Stopping PostgreSQL Windows service
2. Changing md5 to trust in pg_hba.conf file
3. Starting Windows service
4. Accessing database via pgAdmin without a need of password

Is there any way to block this mechanism? I've been thinking about multiple windows users (there's only one administrator account on the machine right now) with limited file change privileges, but I am worried about database functionality and I would prefer a little bit more straight-forward solution.

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for your responses, they were all very helpful.
It's obvious to me now the user accounts are the way - probably the only right way at all.

Comment: "*there's only one administrator account on the machine right now*" - that's the _real_ problem. Don't use the Administrator account for anything else than system maintenance

Comment: Why can the user write to pg_hba.conf?

Comment: The main problem is the computers on which this database (and program using it) is installed isn't managed by me, but usually by someone else. It was created and working this way long before I got to the project and I never really thought about it until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the way to solve the problem is not by looking into PostgreSQL, but by looking into your Windows security. Once someone gains administrator privileges, there is nothing which stops the person from changing anything - this includes your PostgreSQL settings. Even if you set a database password and set proper permissions for the pg_hba.conf file, the unauthorized person can still change the permissions back, or start the database in single user mode (no password required) and modify the passwords.

Create separate Windows user accounts, protect the Admin with a password, and stop using the Admin account for day-to-day work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change all your users to `limited`. Create a user called `postgres` thats also `limited` and set it so that that its the only user that can read/write its own files. You will have your administrator account, that still can do whatever you want to do. Now run the postgres service as the user `postgres` and youre done.

... and stop giving people your admin password -- you should be fine ;)